# Adding a CAShapeLayer to a subView

Tags: swift, uiview, subview, cashapelayer

I trying to add a CAShapeLayer to a smaller UIView on the main view (single view application).  I have the shape Layer animated and reacting to touch gesture to start drawing it. But it is drawn from the center of the main view and I need to be able to move it and constrain it for layout purposes. I have seen another post which seemed to have the same issues but i think i have confused myself more. I have the below code in the viewDidLoad function on the main ViewController.

It is a test project i am playing with to add new functionality to my existing app once I have it working.

I have tried adding a UIView in the MainStoryBoard of the project and adding linking it to the ViewController.swift file (control drag) to create an outlet then adding both shapeLayer & trackLayer to the UIView.

**Code below**

```
@IBOutlet weak var gaugeView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let centre = view.center

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centre, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    // Track Layer Under Gauge
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    //view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    gaugeView.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    // Animated Circular Guage
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    //view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    gaugeView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
  }
```

Once I have the app in the simulator it draws and animates the circle when the view.layer.addSubLayer is not commented out but will not add it to the UIView container with the gaugeView.layer.addSubView is in there.

[image: Screen dump of the main storyboard]

[image: Screen dump once let center = gaugeView.center updated..]

Comment: Do you want to draw a circle?

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with sublayers but is it possible that the added sublayer is outside the frame and the view has `clipsToBounds` true?

Comment: Yes, it works on the main view but not in the uiview I need it in which I can contain in main storyboard.

Comment: Create a custom class of UIView which is circle view and put it on main.storyboard and just assign a custom class to UIView. @MikeyC

Comment: @AbhishekJadhav ok will that also allow me to pass a variable to the UIView to determine the properties of the circle being drawn? ie color and how far the circle is drawn? its going to be used as a progress indicator for a timer counting down.

Comment: If you can show the container view constraints it has in storyboard then it could help to get a solution for your problem.

Comment: How view you want that you can define properties on your custom UIView class, @MikeyC and make sure height and width should be same of your view.

Comment: @Kamran Hi, i have added a screen shot of the Main Storyboard, the UIView is in grey at the top where it needs to be constrained, the grey circle is where the shapeLayer is drawn in green over the trackLayer, I need to get the circle drawn in the grey box which is linked to gaugeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `center` to `gaugeView` `center` instead of `view.center` here,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let centre = CGPoint(x: gaugeView.frame.width/2, y: gaugeView.frame.height/2)
    ...
}
```

**Note:** While using `Autolayout`, `viewDidLoad` is never the right place to use `frame` of a `subView` that is not yet laid out by the `autolayout`. Best place to get and use the `frame` is `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Tried that just now, see second screen dump pic from the simulator.

Comment: That just throws a error as UIBezierPath wants a CGpoint and .bounds is a CGRect

Comment: Yeah. This should fix. `let centre = CGPoint(x: gaugeView.frame.width/2, y: gaugeView.frame.height/2)`

Comment: Genius, that fixed it. mind you i did try that from a previous question on here, but think I forgot the /2 at the ends. Many thanks